# Why isn't all the output showing in the python terminal?

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to print all the combinations of AAA-ZZZ but I can't see all the outputs from the terminal. It prints all from A to Z but when it is displayed overall in the terminal, it only shows the combination from y-z and I can't scroll up anymore.

```
import itertools
for v in itertools.product(['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'],repeat = 3):
  print(v)
```

Comment: indent `print(v)`

Comment: it was indented on my code

Comment: I believe it's because the result was printed too long that terminals can't display the whole output.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code (now that the indent has been fixed). There's something odd about your runtime environment

Comment: what should I do to fix it?

Comment: maybe you can output it to a `txt` file instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain how?

Comment: Basically, terminals have a limited amount of output lines. Try to output the program to a `txt` file. Follow this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp).

Comment: I run the program on the python idle and I was able to see it all.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to buffer size of your `cmd`. You need to change `buffer size` .

Ref: [Check this](https://superuser.com/a/1640331)

or else

**Solution 2**

simply you can save output to list & print them. This will show complete output

```
import itertools
li= []
for v in itertools.product(['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'],repeat = 3):
  #print(v)
    li.append(v)
    print(*li, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If terminal is giving problem, how about saving the result in txt file then reading the output there. I could see all the results in my python IDLE. I used this code to save file and read it on notepad.

```
import itertools
file=open("result.txt",'w')
for v in itertools.product(['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'],repeat = 3):
    file.write(str(v))
file.close()
```